# I'm trying to connect to a progress database with OpenEdge 10.1B Driver using python's pyodbc library but i get error 126 specified module not found

Tags: python, odbc, openedge

I can't provide the exact error but i will try to translate:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\dellserver\uyumsoft$\dlc10\bin\odbctest.py", line 4, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Progress OpenEdge 10.1B Driver};"
pyodbc.InterfaceError: (Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found.(Progress OpenEdge 10.1B Driver, U:\\dlc10\\bin\\pgoe1022.dll) (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

here is my code

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Progress OpenEdge 10.1B Driver};HostName=dellserver;Database=uyum2008;server=192.168.0.253;LogonID=*****;PASSWORD=******")
```

I also get almost exactly the same error when i try to access the database using 64 bit odbc driver
[image: 1]

but there is no error when i use the 32 bit driver...
[image: 2]

Comment: OpenEdge 10.1B on Windows is almost always a 32 bit product. For what it is worth, I would be surprised if the 64 bit ODBC drivers are installed. For that matter I'm not sure if they even exist for 10.1B. I suggest contacting Progress tech support.

Comment: Tom you are right i just installed python 32 bit and the code works now thank you for your answer.